# Troubleshooting ASP.Net MVC validation? Email validates telephones do not

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have a page with the following libraries being loaded:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/expressive.annotations.validate.js"></script>
```

The form has several fields that need to be validated.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 large-4 column end">
        <label class="label radius" for="PrimaryPhone">Home Phone</label>
        <input class="text-box single-line" id="PrimaryPhone" name="PrimaryPhone" placeholder="(###) ###-####" type="tel" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="PrimaryPhone" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 large-4 column en">
        <label class="label radius" for="OtherPhone">Other Phone</label>
        <input class="text-box single-line" id="OtherPhone" name="OtherPhone" placeholder="(###) ###-####" type="tel" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="OtherPhone" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 large-4 column end">
        <label class="label radius" for="WorkPhone">Work Phone</label>
        <input class="text-box single-line" id="WorkPhone" name="WorkPhone" placeholder="(###) ###-####" type="tel" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="WorkPhone" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-6 small-12 end column">
        <label class="label radius" for="EmailAddress">Email Address</label>
        <input class=" text-box single-line" id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" type="email" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="EmailAddress" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The validation is based on the ViewModel

```
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage ="Invalid Email Address")]
    [RegularExpression(@"([\w\.\-_]+)?\w+@[\w-_]+(\.\w+){1,}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; } [Display(Name = "Other Phone")]

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:###-###-####}")]
    [RequiredIf("PrimaryPhone==null && WorkPhone==null", ErrorMessage ="You must enter at least one phone number.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"(?!(?:1-)?(\\$|#|800|833|844|855|866|877|888|900|0))\(?[\\s.-]*([0-9]{3})?[\\s.-]*\)?[\\s.-]*[0-9]{3}[\\s.-]*[0-9]{4}", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid phone number")]
    public string OtherPhone { get; set; }
```

Email address validates properly but phones do not. Also the remote validation attribute has stopped working.

**** added a snippet of the razor code that generates the above

```
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PrimaryPhone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "label radius" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PrimaryPhone, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "(###) ###-####" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PrimaryPhone)
```

Comment: The html you have shown has no `data-val-*` attributes for client side validation so I assume you have disabled it (but then its makes no sense to include `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive`. What validation are you expecting? Are you saying the `[RequiredIf]` or the  `[RegularExpression]` is not working?

Comment: I hadn't noticed that the data-val- stuff was missing. Not sure why or where it was disabled. I didn't do it intentionally.

Comment: Neither of them work

Comment: They certainly will not work client side without the `data-val-*` attributes that are necessary to add the rules to the `$.validator`

Comment: Then the question becomes why are those attributes no longer being placed there? I added some of my razor code above.

Comment: Could be one of 3 possible causes - In `web.config` you have `<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false"/>` (instead of `true`). In `Application_Start()` of `Global.asax` you have `HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = false;`. In the view or its layout you have `@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); }`

Comment: As a side note, why do you have a `[EmailAddress]` attribute (which is a `RegularExpressionAttribute`) and also another `[RegularExpression]` attribute?

Comment: Was a remnant of my troubleshooting. I just forgot to remove one. Also found the problem. Your list of 3 above pointed me an error that got into my Global.asax. I am using expressive validations and for some reason the configuration in the global was partially removed, the result being that the line removing the validation provider was in place but the line adding the ExpressiveAnnotations provider back in was missing.

Answer (score 0):

A partial install/uninstall of Expressive Annotations caused the default validation provider to be removed without a replacement being added. Not sure why the partial install happened. I just added the appropriate provider back in and everything works as expected.